# Not getting multiple values while i am selecting values from drop down in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is my code i am struggling with the multiple values select with jquery if i will select two values i should get two values

```
<html>
<select name="hello[]" id="hello" multiple="multiple" onchange="test(this.value);">
<option value="">Select Value</option>
<option value="1">PHP</option>
<option value="2">JAVA</option>
<option value="3">.NET</option>
<option value="4">ORACLE</option>
<option value="5">DBA</option>
</select>
</html>
<script>
function test(xx)
{

alert(xx);
}

</script>
```

can you please help

in advance Thank You

Comment: you don't need `id="hello[]"`, the braces

Comment: here is the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2uu2df0y/ @Ghost is right

Comment: i have tried with that removing array for even though i didn't get

Comment: @Vamshi.goli see jsfidle which i pointed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to paste the below code and your problem will be solved:)

```
<select name="no_dd[]" id="no_dd" multiple="multiple" onchange="get_values();">
<option value="">Select Value</option>
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
<option value="4">four</option>
<option value="5">five</option>
</select>

<script>
function get_values()
{
  alert($("#no_dd").val());
}
</script>
```

[Live Working Here](http://jsfiddle.net/73gz16w1/2/)

Comment: can you make alert(data) so that it should get what are the values you have selected those values has to get in get_values

Comment: @Vamshi.goli I have made some changes in the code there is no need of data. And one more thing are you including jQuery as it will be needed. i have added the fiddle link also.

Answer (score 1):

Remove that unneeded `[]` square braces in your select markup:

```
id="hello[]" // superfluous
```

Remove those:

```
<select name="hello[]" id="hello" multiple="multiple" onchange="test(this.value);">
```

Sidenote: Check out @gvgvgvijayan's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uu2df0y/) in the comments above.

Comment: i am getting only single value @ghost

Comment: @Vamshi.goli it works just fine, of course you would need to use `ctrl + click` to select multiple values